# ArangoDB pedigree graph traversal

Tags: graph, arangodb

I have an example pedgree with a structure as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDZZ3.png).
My ultimate goal is to extract the ancestry of certain people in the so-called trio format, which is a table with columns `id  mom  dad`.

In my example, the result for the pedigree of the two most recent persons G and H would be

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| id  | mom | dad |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  D  |  A  |  B  |
|  E  |  C  |  B  | 
|  G  |  D  |  E  |
|  H  |  F  |  E  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

The closest thing I could come up with in AQL is the following query.

```
LET last_generation = ['people/G', 'people/H']
FOR person IN last_generation
FOR v, e, p in 1..10 OUTBOUND person is_mom, is_dad
LET role = contains('mom', e._id) ? 'mom': 'dad'
SORT e._from DESC
RETURN DISTINCT {'id': DOCUMENT('people', e._from)._key,
                 'parent': DOCUMENT('people', e._to)._key,
                 'role': role}
```

Altough the result is not yet in the right format, post-processing is easy.

Now my questions are:

1. I am forced to use the `DISTINCT` keyword to ensure uniqueness of rows. However, I would like to avoid unnesseary traversal in the first place rather than filtering. Ideally, I think I need the option `uniqueEdges: "global"`, which is sadly not availabe any more. For instance, after having processed the pedigree of person G, I don't want to traverse the part of the pedigree shared between G and H (i.e., person E and its parents) again. Using `uniqueVertices: "global"` is not an option, because I would then miss the edge between `H --> E`.
2. Is there some kind of option to know the edge collection type during a traversal rather than using the kind of cumbersome checking I do? Please note that it is not an option for me to put the sex into a property of the person (which is reasonable for most humans), because in reality I am dealing with plants, which can (usually) be mother and father at the same time.

Comment: 1. Is there actually a performance issue with your presented query? 2. By edge collection type, do you mean the collection name `is_mom` and `is_dad`, which tells you the gender?

Comment: @CoDEmanX 1. Yes, there is a performance issue, because when I just have duplicate ids in my `last_generation` array, e.g., `['people/G, 'people/G', 'people/G']`, the query runtime increases linearly because the traversal is unnecessarily repeated, although the output stayes the same. 2. Yes, I mean the gender, but this part of the question is no so important.

Comment: Since there is no attribute telling the gender, the proper way to determine the collection name is `PARSE_IDENTIFIER(e._id).collection`.